# Search and replace string but both search string and replace string exceed the character limit

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to update multiple contracts by replacing a single clause with another single clause in MS Word. The clauses are the same for each contract.

The first problem I encounter is that both my search string and my replace string exceed the 255 character limit. I've looked but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Is there a way in VBA for me to get around this 255 char limit?

Comment: Which "suggested solutions"? You won't be happy if we suggest something you've already rejected - and we won't be happy if that happens. Describe what you've tried, with sample code and explain ***how*** it doesn't meet your needs. Use the [edit] link below the question to add the additional information - do ***not*** try to provide it in a comment, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, break the Find & Replace strings into smaller chunks and do however many are required to replace the entire string. Or you might use a macro like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed * your current document look."
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. " & _
      "Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo " & _
      "magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus."
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

where the text to find is:

> On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to
>   coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these
>   galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and
>   other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or
>   diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.

Note the use of the *wildcard* asterisk to shorten the 'Find' string in the macro code. With that, all you need do is ensure your shorter Find string is sufficiently unique to avoid false matches.